# How to export all data from MySQL to Crystal Report

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException' occurred
>   in CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll

Additional information: Failed to load database information.

> Error in File temp_d7e4cda8-7142-49d1-9abe-15731565db74
>   11688_13288_{23E1422F-94E8-4A5B-B860-EDBC25C029F9}.rpt:

Failed to load database information. "

please help.

this is my code

```
        con.Open();
        com = new MySqlCommand("select en_num, id_num, s_name from s_enrolled", con);

        ad = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        ad.SelectCommand = com;
        DataSet da = new DataSet();
        da.Clear();
        ad.Fill(da, "s_enrolled");

        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
        myReport.SetDataSource(da);
        f2.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
        f2.crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        f2.Show();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read my post here :

[Crystal Reports is not showing records from the database, only the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723724/crystal-reports-is-not-showing-records-from-the-database-only-the-columns/53775808#53775808)

It s not enough to set datasource, you must to fill data also (XML)