# Datagridview data printing error in crystal reports

Tags: c#

I am printing `datagridview` data (sales invoice). When I click the print button, no data is shown in the `crystal reports`

Code is Here for Report View:

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPrint obj = new frmPrint();

    CrystalReport1 rpt = new CrystalReport1();

    frmNewSale sale = new frmNewSale();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["GridInovice"]);
    this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

Using `datatable` but click the print button view report is blank.

Comment: Don’t you need to load the report (template) as well https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/crystal-report-loading-without-data-in-c-sharp-winform

Comment: have you tried debugging to see that there is data in `ds.Tables["GridInvoice"]`

Answer (score 0):

Read my post here : I dont see in your code, where you pass data to report

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775808/10785732